# while converting tflite to tfjs i am getting following error

Tags: tensorflow-lite, tensorflow.js, tflite

```
model = tflite.Model.load_model('E:/muzzle/Muzzle.tflite')
```

AttributeError: type object 'Model' has no attribute 'load_model

import tensorflow as tf
import tflite
import tensorflowjs as tfjs

## Load the TFLite model.

model = tflite.Model.load_model('E:/muzzle/Muzzle.tflite')